# How do I use this basic shell script in Mac OS X Terminal?

Tags: macos, shell

I'd like to download videos from Harvard's CS109 course.  I found [this page](https://github.com/vaishaks/cs109-dl-videos#usage) that describes the process. I'm on Mac OS X El Capitan and I've successfully installed rtmpdump.  I'm not sure how to use this script quoted from the page linked to above:

> ./get.sh hq-urls.txt # for high quality versions

What does that line of code do/mean?  Do I have to insert a URL into part of the code?  When I copy and paste

> ./get.sh hq-urls.txt

into the terminal, I get the message: "-bash: ./get.sh: No such file or directory".

It seems like I should copy and paste some url into that code or use some of the other files listed on that github page somehow.

Comment: Did you download the `get.sh` script from that repository? Did you download the `hq-*` or `lq-*` file that contains the links to the videos you want to download? Also do you have `rtmpdump` available on your machine?

Comment: Here's a workaround that doesn't involve coding, for those interested in speeding up the videos: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-download-Harvard-extension-school-videos-for-offline-viewing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download the repository from github. You can do so by typing the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/vaishaks/cs109-dl-videos.git
```

This will download the repository into your current directory. If you have just opened the Terminal, this will be /Users/yourname.
Now you need to cd into this directory. You can do so by typing the following:

```
cd cs109-dl-videos
```

Now you can type the command, as it was posted on the site:

```
./get.sh hq-urls.txt
```